# Get count of items in iBooks

Tags: ipad, books

Is there a way to see how many items are in the iBooks app? I have looked within the app and in Settings>General (where the song count is) to no avail.

I would like help on both MacOS X and iOS 9.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking at the iBooks "All Books" and you Select All and then, with everything still selected you click on one book and keep the mouse button down and then drag just a tiny bit, as if you were going to move the books somewhere--- if you do all that, you will see a little red circle with the number of selected items in it, attached to your cursor. See the picture. The purple arrow is pointing to the red circle with (in this case) "90" in it.

You do have to move the books a little bit but you don't have to move them far for the selected count to show up.

[image: 90 books selected]

Comment: Wow! I thought I was missing something obvious, but this is pretty stupid for Apple. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Great question. I had to experiment. Now I know something new!

Answer (score 0):

Finding the number of books by selecting all and moving them a bit until a number shows up works well if you have a smaller library. But if you have a large library of over 1000 books you can be waiting a long time for a number to pop up!

A better method is go to into iTunes and click on the device icon (shown in the red circle)...

[image]

Assuming you have synced your iPhone or iPad you'll see the device icon in iTunes. The cool thing is that your device doesn't have to be connected when you do this. (If, for some reason, the device icon is missing, just connect your device). When you click on the device icon you'll see a list in the left margin which includes Books. Click on Books and make sure "Sync Books" is checked and that you've selected the "All books" button underneath. This will give you the total number of books in your library.

[image]